# How to use FAB to cycle between options?

Tags: java, android, fragment

I have a fragment in which I want to have a main ImageButton in the center and 2 FAB's on either side that would go to the previous or next Image respectively. I have this set up in XML but can't quite figure out how to make it all fit in Java.

```
public class NewCard extends Fragment {

public static int cardNumber;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_new_card, container, false);
    final ImageButton button = view.findViewById(R.id.card1);

    FloatingActionButton previous = view.findViewById(R.id.previous);
    FloatingActionButton next = view.findViewById(R.id.next);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            cardNumber = 1;
            FinalSubmit fragment = new FinalSubmit();

            getContext().getSharedPreferences("pref", 0).edit().putInt("int", cardNumber).apply();

            address fragment4 = new address();
            FragmentTransaction ft4 = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft4.replace(R.id.frameLayout, fragment4, "FragmentName");
            ft4.commit();


        }});

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So what you want is a Button Image in the background, and two FABs to change the image of the Button Image in the background through a sequence/cycle of pictures?

I got this from a normal activity, not a fragment but I believe it should be the same.

```
ImageButton button;
int nImages=5; //whatever number of images youre cycle goes through
int currentImageId=3; //for example   

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

button= (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imgButton);
button.setOnClickListener(imgButtonHandler);
changeBackground(currentImageId);

fab1= (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.fab1);
fab1.setOnClickListener(imgUp);

fab2= (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.fab2);
fab2.setOnClickListener(imgDown);
}

//so now we are cycling through 1 to 5 

View.OnClickListener imgUp = new View.OnClickListener() {

public void onClick(View v) {
    if (currentImageId==5)  //if we hit 5, and user is still pressing same fab we set 
// it back to the start, 1
{
currentImageId=1;
changeBackground(currentImageId);
return;
}
currentImageId+=1     //Otherwise, just add 1 to the counter
changeBackground(currentImageId);
}
};

View.OnClickListener imgDown = new View.OnClickListener() {

public void onClick(View v) {
if (currentImageId==1) //if we hit 1, and user is still pressing same fab we set 
// it back to the top, 5
{
currentImageId=5;
changeBackground(currentImageId);
return;
}
currentImageId-=1 //Otherwise, just subtract 1 to the counter
changeBackground(currentImageId);

}
};

public void changeBackground(int currentImageId) {
if (currentImageId==1) {
button.setBackgroundResource(image1 path or drawable);

}
if (currentImageId==2) {
button.setBackgroundResource(image2 path or drawable);

}
// and so on and so on... just add all the files 
}
```

It might not be clean and there might be better options if there is too many pictures, but I think this is simple enough and that's how I would do it, not an expert or anything, just trying to help!